# Correct permissions for AWS remote copy

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, s3cmd

I'm using [s3tools](http://s3tools.org) to sync files on a server and an s3 bucket. Specifically, I'm using the sync command. This, however, is not working correctly because I can't find the right permissions to assign to the user I've setup. Almost everything seems to be working but I constanlty get an error from the s3cmd sync command that "Remote Copy failed."

Here's my current policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "SomeSID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
      ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "s3:ListBucket",
          "s3:PutObject",
          "s3:PutObjectAcl",
          "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/some/path",
          "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/some/path/*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know what permissions I should add to make the remote copy possible?

Answer (score 1):

I tested permissions for using the [`sync` command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) provided as part of the **[AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)**.

This policy worked successfully:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "SomeSID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: The `s3:ListBucket` operation works on a Bucket, while the other API calls operate on an Object.

Comment: This didn't work for me on a version-enabled bucket. Any idea why?

Comment: @dxdc Please ask a new Question, providing a copy of your policy and describing what you did and any errors returned.